# JavaFX SceneBuilder Label setText no funciona

Tags: java, javafx

No puedo poner texto a un `Label` en javafx usando `scenebuilder`.

Aquí es donde declaro mi `Label` *(tampoco me sale ningún error)*:

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

import java.util.Calendar;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Main extends Application {
    //Calendar used
    public Calendar cal;
    //variables for get the number of week+current year
    public static int weeks, year;
    @FXML
    //Text areas for the 4 weeks column
    public TextArea week1,week2,week3,week4;
    @FXML 
    //4 control Buttons
    public Button prev,next,next2,prev2, start;
    @FXML
    //Labels
    public Label lab1;
```

Aquí está el método que utilizo para poner el texto:

```
public void ClickStart (ActionEvent event){
        lab1=new Label();
        lab1.setText("hola");
        cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        weeks= cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        week1.setText("Week " + Integer.toString(weeks) + " " + Integer.toString(year));
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
        weeks= cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        week2.setText("Week " + Integer.toString(weeks) + " " + Integer.toString(year));
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
        weeks= cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        week3.setText("Week " + Integer.toString(weeks) + " " + Integer.toString(year));
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
        weeks= cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        week4.setText("Week " + Integer.toString(weeks) + " " + Integer.toString(year));
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -3);
        }
```

Aquí el archivo *.fxml* completo, por si es necesario:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.Main">
  <children>
    <GridPane>
      <children>
        <GridPane>
          <children>
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Monday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Tuesday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Wednesday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Thursday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Friday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Saturday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Sunday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Monday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Tuesday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Wednesday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Thursday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Friday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Saturday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Sunday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Button id="prev" fx:id="prev2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickMinus" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="prev" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Button fx:id="next" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickPlus" prefHeight="29.999900000002526" prefWidth="70.00009999999747" text="next" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Button fx:id="next2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickPlus" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="next" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Button fx:id="prev" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickMinus" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="prev" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea fx:id="week1" prefWidth="200.0" text="Week x Year x" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextArea fx:id="week2" prefWidth="200.0" text="Week x Year x" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextArea fx:id="week4" prefWidth="200.0" text="Week x Year x" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <Label  id= "lab1" fx:id="lab1" prefHeight="40.000099999997474" prefWidth="150.0" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label minHeight="14.0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="533.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="87.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextArea fx:id="week3" prefHeight="100.00009999999747" prefWidth="70.0" text="Week x Year x" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <Button fx:id="start" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickStart" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Start" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
          </children>
          <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
      </children>
      <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
      </columnConstraints>
      <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
  </children>
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Por favor, realiza la pregunta en castellano. Y ya que estamos indica qué error te da, con traza de error a ser posible.

Comment: Perdón, pensaba que estaba en la parte en inglés de esta web. Me corrijo, no obtengo ningún error, pero no me sale texto.

Answer (score 1):

Las variables anotadas con `@FXML` se asignan al cargar el `fxml`.

Estás instanciando un nuevo `label` al inicio de `ClickStart`, por lo cual, **lab1** ya no apunta al componente que se está mostrando en la escena.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de geh es correcta. Lo que tienes que hacer es eliminar la declaración de la etiqueta lab1:

```
public void ClickStart (ActionEvent event){
        lab1=new Label(); // <--- ¡elimina esto!
        ...
```